# How do I bring up getting a raise in an appropriate manner to the correct party?

Tags: professionalism, raise

I just finished my Masters at Northwestern in the US, a relatively prestigious school, in a field relevant to what I do at work. I started here 15 months ago and did not get a raise at the end of my first year. I am pretty young and never asked for a raise before. Is it common for companies to give raises when completing grad school? Who do I talk about getting a raise? My boss, HR? I didn't get to do my annual review with my boss because he has been so busy.

Comment: "*Is it common for companies to give raises when completing grad school?*" It depends. "*Who do I talk about getting a raise?*" It depends. Your best bet is to ask your manager. This is likely to be closed as being company-specific. Fairly sure this topic has come up before as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't automatically get a raise for upgrading your education, you get it for bringing more value to the company.

Go up to your boss and request one by highlighting that you've grown professionally and educationally, and that this makes you a better performer in your role:

> Boss, I've now completed my education and hold X degree. I feel that the courses I've taken over the past year have helped improve my understanding of my tasks and responsibilities, and I feel that I've greatly improved compared to when I started. Would it be reasonable to request a raise at this point?

If he disagrees then you can ask what you need to do to prove yourself. Tackle more responsibilities? Deliver faster on tasks? Improve the quality of your work? etc.

Don't be entirely surprised if you're brushed off with an excuse of the:

> Sorry, but it's just not in the budget right now.

variety.

Comment: downvoter, please explain. This looks like a good answer to me.